# Change Imageview's image outside recyclerview on a clickevent of recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to update Imageview's image on the click of a recyclerview item. Below I have posted my layout screenshot:

[image]

Small images are in recycler view and the big green image is outside of recycler view.

```
//my recycler view adapter code

Context mContext;
List<imgModel> mImgModelList;
String imgUrl;

public imageListAdapter(Context context, List<imgModel> imgModelList) {
    mContext = context;
    mImgModelList = imgModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public imgListHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_card,viewGroup,false);
    imgListHolder imgListHolder = new imgListHolder(view);

    return imgListHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull imgListHolder imgListHolder, int i) {
    final imgModel current = mImgModelList.get(i);
    imgUrl = mImgModelList.get(0).getImgUrl();
    Picasso.get().load(current.getImgUrl()).into(imgListHolder.mImageView);

    imgListHolder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           imgUrl = current.getImgUrl();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mImgModelList.size();
}

class imgListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView mImageView;
    public imgListHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleimg);
    }
}
```

}
// it is the activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list_);

    final Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    final String cateGory = myIntent.getStringExtra("Category");
    String subCategory = myIntent.getStringExtra("subCategory");
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imgListLayout);
    selectedImage =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selectedImg);

    //mToolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.imglistRecycler);
   //mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    data = new ArrayList<>();
   myRef.child(cateGory).child(subCategory).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot category : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (category.child("like").exists()) {
                    imgModel temp = new imgModel(category.child("imgUrl").getValue().toString(), category.child("views").getValue().toString(),
                            category.child("like").getValue().toString(), category.child("share").getValue().toString());
                    data.add(temp);
                }


                mImageListAdapter = new imageListAdapter(imageList_Activity.this,data);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageListAdapter);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(imageList_Activity.this,3));



            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

I want, when user will click any recycler view image means the small images, it will show in big imageview which is outside of recycler view.

Comment: Try this, create an interface in Adapter as onItemClickListener with a method onClick(imgurl) implement that in the Activity. There set the url to imageview?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an interface to update the selected image. create an interface in your adapter eg :

```
 interface UpdateImage{
    void updateImageUrl(String imageurl);
}
```

Now implement this interface in your activity. While setting your adapter just add 
 new imageListAdapter(imageList_Activity.this,data,this);

Now on onClick of the item just call

```
imgListHolder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       imgUrl = current.getImgUrl();
       updateImage.updateImageUrl(current.getImgUrl())
    }
});
```

In your activity, when you implement the above interface you will get an override method updateImageUrl. You can update your image view with this URL.

```
@Override
public void updateImageUrl(String imageurl) {
    Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Raghavendra said, make an interface class then pass it in inside adapter.
Have your activity implements that interface and pass in your activity inside the adapter.

```
Interface OnClick{ 
   public void clickAction()
}

//your adapter class
Adapter {
   //your interface
   public OnClick onclick;
   //set your imageview click activity
   imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      onClick.click;
   }});

//now pass your interface from activity
ImageListActivity implements OnClick {
   //pass to your adapter
   adapter.onClick = this
}
```

Comment: my application got crash after implementing interface, but after seeing your adapter.onClick I realize I have made a mistake. A big thank you.